# How much app can be launched using a single Production certificate?

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, ad-hoc-distribution, iphone-developer-program

I have 3 apps in Appstore with different production certificate, Is there any possibility to have those three apps with single production cerlificatae.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify on the previous answer, you can sign all your app store apps with a **single iOS Distribution certificate**.  You will need to create **3 separate Distribution provisioning profiles**, all tied to the same certificate, but each assigned to the Application ID for their specific app.  If you have an existing app store distribution certificate, you can simply use it when creating your new provisioning profiles - simply check the box next to your certificate when you create or edit the profile.

So you will have one cert (e.g. App Store Cert), and three profiles like this:

App One:

> ```
> App One Provisioning Profile (App Store Distribution)
> Cert: App Store Cert
> App Id: com.example.appOne
> ```

App Two:

> ```
> App Two Provisioning Profile (App Store Distribution)
> Cert: App Store Cert
> App Id: com.example.appTwo
> ```

App Three

> ```
> App Three Provisioning Profile (App Store Distribution)
> Cert: App Store Cert
> App Id: com.example.appThree
> ```

Unless something has changed, I do not believe Apple will even allow you to have more than 2 active Distribution certificates at any given time.  They allow two only so that you can create a second when your current cert is about to expire.  This gives you time to ensure all your developer have the new cert prior to the old expiring, but the old will still work in the transition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have different profiles for each application. Else certificate does not matter in terms of number i.e., you can have same certificate for multiple apps only catch is you need to have different provisioning profiles for each application.

Comment: i am geting a error that no matching provisioning profile found for application. None of the valid provisioning profile allowed the specified entitlements.

Comment: Which xCode do you use?

Comment: In project settings are you using manual code signing or automatic?

Comment: automatic. my doubt is do i want to create a production certificate to add while creating a distribution provisioning profile. to make sucess or i can use an existing production certifiate

Comment: For production you need to create distribution certificate.

Comment: Yes, you can use the existing distribution certificate with your new distribution profiles.